# Testing for structural break in the covariance

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, covariance, vector-autoregression

I estimated a bivariate VAR(p) model and assume that there exist two covariance regime $\Sigma_1$ for the period 1 to $T_B$ and $\Sigma_2$ for the period $T_B+1$ to $T$. I am now interest in testing whether or not $\Sigma_1$ is equal to $\Sigma_2$. In the paper of Lütkepohl and Lanne, Identifying Monetary Policy Shocks via Changes in Volatility, 2010, they state the following:

"Assuming again two different regimes for illustrative purposes and denoting the reduced form residual covariance matrices in the two regimes by $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, respectively, a test of interest is, for example,

$H_0$: $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2$ versus $H_1$: $\Sigma_1 \neq \Sigma_2$

In other words, the null hypothesis specifies that there is no regime change. Since we consider reduced-form parameters here, there is no identification problem. For our three-equation model the asymptotic null distribution of the corresponding LR statistic is chi-squared (6), provided that LR tests have standard asymptotic properties. [...]

The test is in fact a Chow-type
test. Its small sample properties may not be ideal, as pointed out by Candelon and Lutkepohl (2001). According to these results the test may reject a true null hypothesis too often in small samples."

What really puzzled me is the last paragraph about the chow-type test. I looked up the paper of Candelon and Lutkepohl (2001) and stumbled across the following test statistic:

Let T be the full sample, $T_1$ the first regime and $T_2$ the second regime. The model is estimated in all three regimes, denote the residuals as $\hat{u}$, $\hat{u}^1$ and $\hat{u}^2$, respectively. Moreover, define

$\hat{\Sigma}_{12}=T_1^{-1}\sum^{T_1}_{t=1}\hat{u}_t\hat{u}_t'+T_2^{-1}\sum^{T}_{t=T-T_2+1}\hat{u}_t\hat{u}_t'$

$\hat{\Sigma}_{1}=T_1^{-1}\sum^{T_1}_{t=1}\hat{u}^1_t\hat{u}^1_t$ and $\hat{\Sigma}_{2}=T_1^{-1}\sum^{T_1}_{t=1}\hat{u}^2_t\hat{u}^2_t$.

The sample split test statistics can be written as follows:

$\lambda=(T_1+T_2) \log |\hat{\Sigma}_{12}|-T_1 \log |\hat{\Sigma}_1|-T_2 \log |\hat{\Sigma}_2| \overset{H_0}{\sim} \chi^2(k)$

I don't get why this test is relevant in this scenario, because it only test whether or not the parameters contain structural change, and not the covariance matrices (right?).

Now I have spent an enternity on finding a test for this. The test which I did find in several paper, did not fit my coding skills (am using R software), hence I need something simplier. Any tips or hints in what direction I should focus are appreciated! Thanks!